# Load the images from the Gallery into gridview

Tags: android, gridview, android-lazyloading

This [LazyLoading library](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) helps me to load the images from the internet. Can i use this library to load the images from the gallery.

```
 imageLoader.DisplayImage(url, image);
```

What should i send the argurment to display the image from the gallery

**Note** I'm having the path of the images in the ArrayList

**Imp Note** : I'm also having the ArrayList of **byteArray** (one byte array resembles to one image). So then how can i use the library

**Edit** I encrypted some images from the gallery and stored in SDCard and i need to display the encrypted images in my app(I know the path of the encrypted images) Encryption is done in **Byte[]** level.

Please suggest me. ThankYou

Answer (score 0):

> Can i use this library to load the images from the gallery?

Gallery itself a application which is showing images from your local folder. So if you have a local image you can show it by its path in your App.
You just need to add `file` in your image path to make path as URI.
Like

```
String URL = "file:///mnt/sdcard/image.png"; // from SD card
```

Comment: I tried it..It was giving **java.lang.ClassCastException: libcore.net.url.FileURLConnection cannot be cast to java.net.HttpURLConnection**

Comment: What you are actually trying? Can you put some more code?

Comment: Why did you encrypt the images?

Comment: Its part of the logic of my app!! So that the encrypted images cannot be visible in the main gallery